# ASP.NET MVC 404 Error for SubDirectories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-404

I've added a custom 404 page to my asp.net mvc application. It works totally great except for on some paths that have been excluded from the MVC routing engine. As you can imagine, I'd like my 404 page to work for those URLs as well.

So the question is: Can I add some setting in IIS I can use to just point it to the 404 page's endpoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a `StaticContentController` that simply opens a file stream and returns it to the browser. The path is controlled tightly by the routing engine to avoid security issues, and it is heavily cached.

A note on the file stream, when I first implemented it, I was using MVC's `return File(...` method, but that locks the file while it is streaming it, so I had some instances of file contention for files that were written to *and* served concurrently. That's why I switched to returning a `FileStream`, so I could pass the correct file sharing options that allow for the file to be written to by another process.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any custom setting on IIS.

Works for me. I have the following settings set in web.confg

My RegisterRoutes method is as below

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
    }
```

Comment: Well I mentioned that the URLs where this is not working are explicitly excluded from the routing engine. This is because I have static content in these directories that has no need to be processed by asp.net mvc ... however, when a 404 occurs, I'd still like for the asp.net mvc 404 page to be used.